\subsubsubsection defined using \@startsection duplicates the section name
It is a known thing that you can define your own level of sections using \@startsection (see this answer for example). You can define a subsubsubsection, for example, instead of a paragraph.
However, if I rename the counter from paragraph to something else, it for some weird reason starts duplicating the subsubsubsection (subsubsubsubsection) name in the text of the main text. For instance, the following minimal working example
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, oneside]{article}

\makeatletter
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{6}
\newcounter   {subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\newcounter{subsubsubsubsection}[subsubsubsection]

\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection      {\thesubsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsubsection}
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsubsection.\@arabic\c@subsubsubsubsection}

\newcommand\subsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsection}%
                                           {4}{\z@}%
                                           {3.25ex\@plus .2ex \@minus 1ex}%
                                           {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                           {\centering\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\subsubsubsubsection{\@startsection{subsubsubsubsection}%
                                              {5}{\z@}%
                                              {3.25ex\@plus .2ex \@minus 1ex}%
                                              {1.5ex \@plus .2ex}%
                                              {\centering\normalfont\normalsize}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \section{Section name}
  \subsection{Subection name}
  \subsubsection{Subsubection name}
  \subsubsubsection{Subsubsubection name}
  \subsubsubsubsection{Subsubsubsubection name}
\end{document}

produces the following text:

However, if I change the counters in \subsubsubsection and \subsubsubsubsection definitions to paragraph and subparagraph respectively, the duplicated section names disappear. What kind of black magic is this?

You also have to define \subsubsubsectionmark etc. with exactly one argument. Or use a package/class that provides an interface for defining new sectioning commands.

Thank you! Indeed, I added \let\subsubsubsectionmark@gobble and \let\subsubsubsubsectionmark@gobble, and the duplicated section names disappeared. Now I'll try to understand in detail why it works, and post it as an answer if I succeed.

The question got closed before I could do that. @startsection calls @sect, while @sect calls <name>mark. The first argument to @startsection is treated as the section level's name, so in my case, \subsubsubsectionmark is called. If it's not defined, its argument is just printed (why doesn't that lead to an error?..)
